# Java Maven; org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$CyclicDependencyException: Cyclic dependency

Tags: java, selenium, dependency-injection, cucumber, picocontainer

Currently seeing the exception listed below:

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$CyclicDependencyException: Cyclic dependency: [class pageObjects.accounts.login.ForgotPassword_PO, class pageObjects.tutors.Tutors_PO, class pageObjects.accounts.login.Login_PO, class pageObjects.accounts.login.ForgotPassword_PO, class stepDefinitions.accounts.SignUp_Steps]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:265)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
```

I have inspected the recommended areas (Classes) related to the issue but cannot locate any repeated injected classes etc:
Cyclic dependency:

```
[class pageObjects.accounts.login.ForgotPassword_PO, class pageObjects.tutors.Tutors_PO, class pageObjects.accounts.login.Login_PO, class pageObjects.accounts.login.ForgotPassword_PO, class stepDefinitions.accounts.SignUp_Steps]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add more information to the question.

Comment: The classes listed in the the exception form the cycle.

Comment: thank you for the comment @mpkorstanje  do you know whether there is a way to further debug the issue in intelij? I have tried to break down the issue really minutely but still cant find any resolution

Comment: I'd recommend pen and paper or a whiteboard to draw out the dependencies between all involved classes.

Comment: ok thanks @mpkorstanje its odd because I have never experienced this issue before, my understandings was you shoudnt experience any issues injecting classes into another as long as a given class doesnt try to inject the same class more than once?

Comment: For example Class A can have class B injected into it and Class B can have class A injected into it.

Comment: Some DI containers support that. Pico container does not.

Comment: ok thanks again @mpkorstanje can you recomend another replacement rather than using pico container, or do you feel its best suited with Java and cucumber?

Comment: It's better to fix your cycle. Do the pen and paper thing. It really helps.

Comment: @mpkorstanje ok thank you, appreciate the help, hope you have a great evening.

Comment: Circular dependency is a bad thing regardless of the container used. It means poor separation of responsibilities inside the app, maybe you need to move some functions between your A & B or introduce third class, that will be dependent on A or/and B, but not backward etc

Comment: thanks @xeye looks like I will need need to create a third entity to handle both A and B and ensure there is also separation between A and B so they do not become connected.